# debug error, abort has been called when assigning a value to an Eigen matrix element

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm writing a finite element program, and I need a library for matrix alocation and manipulation. Eigen seemed fine.

But I got this weird bug where:

```
double numero = get_coordenada(elemento.no1, 'x', vector_de_nos);
M_coord_nos(1, 1) = numero;
```

works fine.

But this:

```
M_coord_nos(1, 1) = get_coordenada(elemento.no1, 'x', vector_de_nos);
```

Or this:

```
M_coord_nos(1,1) = vector_nos[elemento.no1].x;
```

Gives me a debug error, abort() has been called.

vector_nos is a vector of struct_no, which is made from three double values, x, y and z. get_coordenada is a function that returns a double value.

I'm stumped. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Also, please indent your code with four spaces so it will be displayed properly.

Comment: I rewrote the code to make a minimal complete and verifiable example, and the thing works. Bollocks. I still don't know what can be wrong. I'll try making a minimal from the original code (too big to post)

Comment: [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might also help.